# Porque não devo usar o Jquery com o React?

Tags: jquery, react

Qual seria a desvantagem ao usar o jQuery com o React ? Pois estou transformando um site que está todo em jQuery para React e vejo em muitos fóruns o pessoal dizendo que não é uma boa prática usar o jQuery junto ao React porém sem nenhuma explicação completa para o desuso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O React já traz sua propia maneira de manipular o DOM, então usando jquery tu estaria forçando o react a trabalhar muito mais, e renderizar os elementos mais vezes, já que isso não estaria sobre controle dele. Da uma olhada sobre como o React manipula o DOM, sobre o virtual dom que ele cria, para optimizar a re-renderização de elementos na tela, e além disso, tu consegue fazer tudo mais facilmente com React, não tem sentido para usar Jquery